# Помогите с ajax скриптом в таблице

Tags: ajax

Я новичок, не могу разобраться в скрипте. Есть таблица которая заполняется с датафрейма. надо ввести данные, чтобы они передались с той строки, в которую пользователь внес. Номер id я понял как передать, а вот, то что вводит пользователь, почему-то передается только с первой строки. Как передать введенные данные со строки в которую вводит пользователь?

```js
    $(document).ready (function () {
      $(".save").bind('click', function() {
        $. ajax ({
          url: '/save/',
          type: "POST",
          data: ({name: $('#mass').val(),
                  id:$(this).data('id')
          }),

          success: function () {
              $("#information").text('записано');
            }

        });
      });
    });
```

```html
 <td>

<form action="/save/" method="POST" name="save" id = 'form' >
<input class=mass id='mass'  type="number" name="mass" />
<input class='save' data-id={{row[6]}} type="button" value="Записать">
</form>

</td>
```